# Need to create iOS notification that does not go away until dismissed

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, alert

I need to create an iOS notification that does not go away until dismissed.  The built in iOS reminder app behaves this way.  How can I replicate this behavior in my own code?  The iOS reminder app behaves like this:

- If the screen is locked when the reminder comes in then a banner appears and, if not dismissed, the banner re-appears for a while each time the phone is locked. The local notifications I have experimented with go away after the screen is unlocked and do not re-appear.  How can I make the message re-appear until dismissed in my own app?
- If the screen is not locked when the reminder comes in then a big message window pops up.  See picture in link below.  How can I make this kind of window pop up when my app is running in the background (or suspended)?  The alerts I have experimented with do not appear when app is suspended.

[iOS reminder message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGiyY.png)

Comment: Short answer; you can't. The in-built apps can do things that other apps can't. This is one of those things

Comment: Thanks Paulw11.  That confirms what I was thinking.  I looked at how other 3rd party reminder apps worked and none of them worked like the built in iOS reminder app.  Now I can move forward and work within the limitations Apple gives us.